# Am I setting the authorization header programmatically correctly in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, symfony-3.4

I have implemented OAuth into symfony 3.4. I can now use the access token and bearer in the authorize as shown below to authorize based upon an id. This works in postman.

[PostMan Authorization example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrtOt.png)

However, the issue is when I come to programmatically send the same data in the authorization header in Symfony like shown in the code snippet below. It doesn't authorize though they are the same. Is this the correct way to setting the authorization header?

If I remove the authorization header above and depend on the code to authorize using the same credentials it will deny it.

I am confident everything is working accordingly. The issue is authorization using headers->set I believe

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer NjBmMDg4M2I2NzkwZDRmZGVjN2VmYWNmNjQyMDg5Mzk1ZTAzZjQ0MzYyMmIzMDZjMjBlMjFlNzNkZTRhMDNhZA');
```

Comment: if you're doing this on a dev machine and have its environment set to dev, you could just take a look at the profiler what happens there (all requests appear there, usually - there's a last 10 requests list somewhere)

Comment: You seem to be setting headers on your INCOMING request.    is this what you are trying to do ?    if so, when/where are you trying to do this ? in your controller action ?   this wil not work, as it will not even reach that point (assuming you are using fosoauth or something)